# The medieval abbreviation eccƚie

Tags: medieval-latin, abbreviations

The abbreviation `eccƚie` is common in medieval latin texts, like this:
[image: latin text]
which is from page 78 of [Placita de quo Warranto](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2R9DAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). It can also be seen in [this text](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=x-IHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR25&lpg=PR25&dq=%22ecclie%22&source=bl&ots=u5xfqQ_tJY&sig=tnPlSj5rRPRVho6uRYAqlpSBBh0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ecclie%22&f=false) and [this text](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gW5MAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=%22ecclie%22&source=bl&ots=3dFik0jnAx&sig=LuKPhyZpH3SU5CrsYGWTm-NMNeQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ecclie&f=false). There is a horizontal bar through the vertical of the `l` indicating abbreviation.

Presumably, it stands for one of [the eccles words](http://latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/eccles) in some form or another, something to do with the church. The text above is (I think) about John, the rector of Eversholt church, paying the king for a licence to be preacher.

But just what full latin word, with what meaning, is implied by the abbreviation `eccƚie`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Classical Latin the Genitive and Dative, first declension are **-ae** but in Medieval Latin, **-e.**  So this is the abbreviated form of **ecclesie.** ***"of the church."***

Not all through-strikes have the same significance: though *per* and *pro* in this passage might originally have had  / and - strikes.

> Johannes persona ecclesie de EVERESHOLT dat domino Regi dimidiam
>   marcam pro licencia habenda **...**

The National Archive has posted  [beginners](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/latin/beginners/) and [advanced](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/latin/advanced/) Latin course on its website.
The abbreviations can be found on pages posted by Wikipedia under 'Scribal [Abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation)' and Archive under ***"Sigla"***

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel for restoring the link, etc.